# How do I completely reset a GIT repo when I completely remake the entire project?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm working on a project for a company, Well I was brought in to fix a project and ended up just remaking everything entirely. It was the only way, it's a game and most of the code was made with the first version of the engine and wouldn't fit with the newest version of the engine. So I've completely remade it, but it won't let me just push the changes when I delete everything and paste the new source in.

I'm also not the main owner of the repository, it's the main guy at the company who has it in his bitbucket account. I do have read/write access though. I would have asked him to do some stuff for me but though he's the main guy he's only the main artist and not super technical. So I'd like to be able to do it all on my own without having to walk him through.

I just want to completely clear a project and paste in the new source and send it in and have that take the place of the old code on the main repository. Is there a way I can do this with git?

Comment: How about "fetch/merge", "delete everything", "commit", "put/add new code", "commit", "push"?

Comment: I tried something like that but it still shows a lot of deleted files that aren't needed anymore still on the source view. I'm not a Git "master", is there a way to get Git to recognize the things that are deleted now?

Comment: @G1i1ch use `git rm` to let git know about removed files.

Comment: What shows up when you run `git status`? Do these file show as deleted there? If so, do as @xaizek said: use `git rm`.

Comment: If you `rm`, git automatically identifies them as deleted, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems rather drastic.  But...

You need something along the lines of (this is not tested--it is intended to give you the flavor of what you need).  I'm making lots of assumptions about your environment

```
# get the current stuff
git pull origin master

# label the location you are about to nuke.  Pick a name that suites you.
# while this is not strictly necessary, I'd highly recommend it
git checkout master
git branch release_0.9
git push origin release_0.9

# change to a new branch
git checkout -b release_1.0

# remove all the old files
ls | xargs rm -rf

# copy in your files here

# add all the new files
git add -A

# commit and push your branch
git commit
git push origin release_1.0

# update master
git push . HEAD:master

# push the new version of master
git push origin master
```

Please do not blindly execute these commands.  Understand and test them first.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk I'll have to look into some of the changes :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Leave the original intact, branch off of it as your own GitHub directory, and make changes to it, instead. And it is best advised to break the revisions down to smaller stages ... first retrofitting as much of the newer developments into the legacy code as you can, then changing the core infrastructure and making whatever remaining changes afterwards that you couldn't make beforehand. But even that should be staged, using stubs in the first stage as need be, to pun the newer material added after the infrastructure change.

Then the diffs will be more cleanly stratified, and you will have each stage present (including the original one) as benchmarks for regression testing ... which should be an essential part of the process at every step of the way.

Never throw out the old, and become adept at thinking in 4 dimensions, not 3. A project is not a 3-dimensional snapshot of the world-of-today, but a 4-dimensional chain comprising its entire extent in spacetime - i.e. its whole history. A history is just as important as a snapshot, if not more. In the future, you or someone else may end up finding that parts of the original way of doing things were better and need to be backtracked to or reintegrated or even branched off of separately. The archive is made for storing histories (i.e. 4-dimensional objects in spacetime), not things-as-they-are-today. That mode of thinking ... especially prevalent amongst those who are too young to have been in the world long enough to know better ... of being stuck in the flat 3-D world-of-the-moment is a form of temporal myopia known as Presentism; and should be avoided - both for creative endeavors and in other areas of life.